# SQL SERVER: How to select Ids from the table which has values only in 1 or 3

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Consider the following table,

```
|  Id  | Value |
----------------
|  1   |  1    |
|  1   |  3    |
|  1   |  1    |
|  2   |  2    |
|  2   |  3    |
```

How to write a sql query to select Id which has values only in 1 or 3(considering above table, required id=1)

Comment: Select * from T where id = 1 and value in (1,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id from <TABLE> t1 where not exists 
  (select 1 from <TABLE> t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.value not in (1,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

From above answer,

select id from  t1 where not exists 
  (select 1 from  t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.value not in (1,3)) GROUP BY ID;

From question

> 1 or 3 
>   it will be 1 and 3